# Observable from Func delegate

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive, reactive, observer-pattern

Is there a method or library function that would accept `Func<T>` and `return IObservable<T>` by invoking it?

The functionality should be probably equal to

```cs
public IObservable<T> Create<T>(Func<T> factory){
  try{
    return Observable.Return(factory());
  }
  catch(Exception ex){
    return Observable.Throw<T>(ex);
  }
}
```

Seems like a lot of code for something so simple. Is there something out of the box?

I checked `Observable.Return`, `Observable.Generate` and some others, but could not find anything that would accept `Func<T>` delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Observable.Start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229036(v=vs.103)) method to create an observable from a `Func<>` like this:

```
Func<int> func = () => Random.Shared.Next();

IObservable<int> obs = Observable.Start(func);

obs.Subscribe(it => Console.WriteLine(it));
```